# How to decode nested json on to a custom class with array in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, nested, alamofire, decodable

I am getting `nil` when trying to parse a nested json response onto a custom decodable response class.

#### Custom Response Classes:

```
class User: Decodable, Encodable {

    var name: String?
    var email: String?
    var token: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case email
        case token
    }

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.name = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.email = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .email)
        self.token = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .token)
    }
}

class ResponseData: Decodable {

    let body: [User]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case users
        case body
    }

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let response = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy:CodingKeys.self, forKey: .body)
        self.body = try response.decode([User].self, forKey: .users)
    }
}

class ResponseRoot: Decodable {
    let data : ResponseData?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case data }

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.data = try? container.decode(ResponseData.self, forKey: .data)
    }
}
```

#### Json Response for Parsing,

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "errorMessage": null,
    "data": {
        "headers": {},
        "body": [
            {
                "name": "Alex",
                "email": "alex@b.c",
                "password": "1234",
                "token": "1234",
                "loginStatus": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "Einstein",
                "email": "e@b.c",
                "password": "1234",
                "token": "A valid token",
                "loginStatus": 1
            }
        ],
        "statusCode": "OK",
        "statusCodeValue": 200
    }
}
```

#### Alamofire Call,

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.queryString, headers: nil)
         .validate()
         .responseJSON { response in

            switch (response.result) {

                case .success( _):

                do {
                    let users = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseRoot.self, from: response.data!) // getting users = nil
                    completion((users.data?.body!)!)

                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    completion([])
                }

                 case .failure(let error):
                    print("Request error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    completion([])
             }
```

Now, `let users = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseRoot.self, from: response.data!)` does not create any exception but `users` is nil.

Comment: Statuscode 400 is a server error, it's not related to the decoding part. And never print `localizedDescription` of a `DecodingError`. You throw away the comprehensive error message.

Comment: isn't it request error from HTTP request in the case .failure? the API call is failed so it does not do the decode line

Comment: I am getting valid data in response

Comment: @aiwiguna & @vadian, I updated the post. Error was from previous log. Sorry for misunderstanding. But now I am getting `nil`.

Comment: It looks like you could remove half of your code. Codingkeys aren't really required as your variable names are the same as the keys. Initializers are also not required inside of the structs. All you would have to do is call JSONDecoder.decode(ResponseRoot, from: data) and it should work.

Comment: Remove all question marks from the property types, comment out the initializers and CodingKeys and  `print(error)`. The error tells you exactly what's wrong and where.

Comment: @vadian got the error `Failed to load: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structs you made are (in my opinion) overly complicated. They could be the following:

```
class User: Codable {

    var name: String
    var email: String
    var token: String
}

class ResponseData: Codable {

    let body: [User]?
}

class ResponseRoot: Codable {
    let data : ResponseData
}
```

Then just call `JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseRoot.self, from: data)` inside of a try catch block.

Comment: Just wow. Thanks a lot. it worked with `let users = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseRoot.self, from: response.data!)` inside try.

Comment: However, if my keys and variables name were different, what was the wrong in my implementation?

Comment: If you would for instance have a JSON key called usrid, that stood for a users id, but you would like to have a that key be decoded to a variable called userID, you would use codingkeys like this:
```enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case userID = "usrid"
    }```

Comment: Yes I know. What I was asking for is, why my previous code did not parse correctly when I have done all right, although overworked.

Comment: Not really sure, could be because of the initializers in each separate struct, or the fact that all variables were optional. Not really sure, sorry. You could just remove both those things one by one, and see when it starts working?